# Is robot_pose_ekf acting correctly?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working towards getting gmapping to work on my turtlebot clone right now but I keep getting the following

```
[ WARN] [1326075941.066724233]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1326075941.0667, global_pose stamp: 1326075940.4574, tolerance: 0.3000
[ WARN] [1326075941.066806436]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
```

So I try `rosrun tf view_frames` to see if there's anything wrong: [view_frames.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13260765019373684.png)

Seems like the only weird area is the broadcast rate of /odom->/base_footprint of 10000Hz. So I did a `rosservice call /robot_pose_ekf/get_status`

```
status: Input:
 * Odometry sensor
   - is active
   - received 2578 messages
   - listens to topic /odom
 * IMU sensor
   - is NOT active
   - received 2686 messages
   - listens to topic /imu/data
 * Visual Odometry sensor
   - is NOT active
   - received 0 messages
   - listens to topic 
Output:
 * Robot pose ekf filter
   - is active
   - sent 215 messages
   - pulishes on topics /robot_pose_ekf/odom and /tf
```

What I find odd is the IMU is supposedly not active yet `rostopic hz /imu/data` shows

```
    subscribed to [/imu/data]
average rate: 20.001
    min: 0.048s max: 0.052s std dev: 0.00078s window: 20
average rate: 20.001
    min: 0.048s max: 0.052s std dev: 0.00066s window: 40
average rate: 20.000
    min: 0.048s max: 0.052s std dev: 0.00054s window: 60
```

Anybody has any idea how I can fix this problem? Or am I looking at the wrong area (robot_pose_ekf seems to be the issue right now since I'm using it to handle my transform broadcast)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12562/is-robot_pose_ekf-acting-correctly?/) by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2268 on 2012-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found where the problem was by looking through the rxconsole printouts:

```
[WARN]    Could not transform imu message from IMU to base_footprint. Imu will not be activated yet.
```

Turns out that the frame_id when I published the /imu/data was not set to gyro_link to match the URDF. That's why robot_pose_ekf could not work properly.

For those of you reading this who are just starting out ROS/navigation stack, it would be good to remember the difference between "topic" and "frame", and the need to connect the two when publishing the topic.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on 2012-05-23**:
Hey, I get the same error . When I echo  the /imu/data I see that the frame_id was set to gyro_link. Could there be any other cause for the problem?

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-05-23**:
check all the topics frame_id and compare with what you have in your tf tree (rosrun tf view_frames). they should match. robot_pose_ekf provides the transform odom->base_footprint, so ensure this is broadcast

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-01**:
I had the same problem, TF tree was connected but had the same error, Could not transform imu message from /base_imu to /base_footprint.  It was solved by changing the frame id of IMU to /base_footprint............Thats it